# website is 302, how to obtain the redirected source

Tags: referrer, http-status-code-302

Website is redirected access, how to obtain the redirected source

I can't get the referrer after website is redirected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.